# How to password protect a category page / not posts?

Tags: plugins, categories

I have seen this question here but the answer was a plugin ( cat-pass ) that would password protect all the posts under the category.
I am looking to password protect the category itself and not showing the content under it until a password is written.

It is the same as if the post is protected but for categories.

I hope this makes sense.

kind Regards